# Using Sbt as BSP Server in Kubernetes

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm looking for a solution that would enable me to deploy Sbt as a BSP server or any other protocol, on Kubernetes, and use my IDE to work with it via, say, port forwarding.

Is this technically possible? Before going into things like DevSpace or Okteto, I was wondering, if anyone could share their experience trying to do it with SBT Server capability directly.

Comment: Why exactly do you want to do this?

Comment: Questioning my motives euh :)

Comment: In short Problem with remote contracting team and working in corporate with bad dev culture, so we are trying work arounds their restriction. Guys can't even run integration test that involve things like test container because they are locked in Windows amazon workspace. Hope that's enough detail :)

Comment: Looking into Okteto right now, but if there are native solution i'm also curious

Comment: Can they just install docker for windows and WSL 2 on that?

Comment: no Amazon workspace does not support installing docker, it is official